# ArrayList of String Arrays save last record only

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need some help with my ArrayList in Java. I spent long time debugging, but still. The problem is - I save some data from database to string array and save this array to ArrayList, in the output it saves only last element multiple times. Looks like it simply rewrite it.

```
String[] result=new String[2];
String userId=Personal_Organizer.userProfile.getUserID();
ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();           
params.add(userId);
String query1 = "select * from tblMemos where "
        + "_user_id = ?";

int rows;
System.out.println(query1);
executeQueryP(query1, params);

ArrayList<String[]> fetched = new ArrayList<String[]>();
int i=0;

try {
    while(rs.next()) {

        result[0] = rs.getString(2);
        result[1] = rs.getString(3);

        System.out.print("Counter: "+i);
        try{
            fetched.add(i,result);//here tried just .add(result) and output is same.
            i++;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exceptional exception "+e);
        }

    }
    // Just to check. I have 2 records in DB and it shows last record twice 
    System.out.println(fetched.size());
    System.out.println(fetched.get(0)[0]);
    System.out.println(fetched.get(1)[0]);
}
// ...
```

Comment: @pratim_b rs is Result Set instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a new array instance in each iteration:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    result = new String[2];
    result[0] = rs.getString(2);
    result[1] = rs.getString(3);
    fetched.add(result);
}
```

Otherwise you are adding the same array instance multiple times to the List, and each iteration overwrites the content of that array with the latest data.